# Windows emulator on ubuntu with GPU passthrough?

Tags: windows, games, gpu, emulation

I have a Ubuntu and Windows dual boot, I use Ubuntu for everything except gaming.(Wine/dxvk doesn't cut it) Now I'd like to not have to reboot when I feel like playing a game, which sometimes is only 10 minutes. So I want to have a Windows 10 emulator, with GPU passthrough. My machine has a Titan Xp, but I have an additional RX480 which I am willing to use for Windows 10. So is what I want possible?
And if so, does anyone have a tutorial for it?

Thanks!

Edit:
I of course mean having an emulator(e.g. virtualbox) run Windows 10, and also have the emulator(virtualbox in this case) also pass the GPU to the VM(Windows 10). So I can just install the AMD driver on Windows, and have Windows be in full controll over it.(And thus get excellent performance)

Comment: @user535733 I mean a emulator that allows the GPu to be passed through, and run windows on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you call an "emulator" is actually called a "Virtual Machine".
I believe you have all the right HW to achieve what you want, so you're starting on the right foot. Basically you have to:

- verify you have a IOMMU compatible system
- have a UEFI compatible second GPU
- install your Amd second GPU in a PCI port on your motherboard
- blacklist amdgpu drivers and load a couple of kernel functions (using GRUB it's easier)
- "detach" the amd GPU via software using VFIO module
- create a VM (my advise is KVM + libvirt) and configure your system to pass the detached AMD gpu to it.
- Start the VM and install Windows 10 and drivers as usual. (You also have to attach the second GPU to a second monitor, and pass another mouse and keyboard through USB to the VM: host and guest will be as two whole different PCs)

Don't expect the same performance as you run everything in dual boot anyway, but with patience and some tweaks you can easily reach 80%. It's a good idea to have different GPUs for the host and the guest (nvidia and ATI), like you do. this is a good starting point.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1106418/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Also, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the external site into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link to the external site at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! WIll give it a try.

Comment: @Fabby Ok, sorry my mistakes. I will do it better in the future. Thank you

Comment: No apologies needed: the reviewers are here to help you! **;-)**